# What is Apache HTTP Server clustering?

Tags: apache-2.2

What does Apache server clustering actually means? As I have read : it is related to configuring Apache web server in load balancing, with high availability mode.

But I am not able to grasp the term for this situation. My first impression to this term was that, there should be more than one web servers handling a single host name. For example:- There is a website www.abc.com, which is resolved at 10.10.10.21:80,and on 10.10.10.22:80

Please describe me! :(

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: If you are looking for a fast and robust clustering, have a look at `nginx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hear about web clustering, a few different technologies come to mind. The option you cite is what is typically called DNS Round-robin load balancing. With this, both IP addresses are listed as DNS `A` records for the domain. Some clients will resolve one IP address and some will resolve the other. This is a very simplistic way of load balancing, and can usually only work on websites that don't maintain any state about the user's session.

The preferred method of load balancing is to have two or more webservers behind one large load balancer. In this case, the website IP address resolves to the IP of the load balancer, and then the load balancer proxies the user's requests to the back-end webservers, distributing the load between all of the active nodes as necessary.

> For example:- There is a website
>   www.abc.com, which is resolved at
>   10.10.10.21:80,and on 10.10.10.22:80

Just for your information, DNS resolution has nothing to do with TCP (or UDP for that matter) port numbers. DNS will only resolve to an IP address, and then the application (web browser in this case) needs to know what port to connect to.